# how do I filter using grep with logins ending with a specified number

Tags: grep

grep
how can I find all the user logins that end with 88 and 89 ?
I can get logins ending with a number if I do
grep "[0-9]" filename

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show those ending in 88 and 89, you can use `grep -e "88$" -e "89$"`

The '$' notates the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to use character classes: `[0-9]` is a character class that means "all the digits from 0 until 9". You can use more specific sets as well. For instance, `[89]` means "either `8` or `9`". Finally, in regular expressions, `$` means "the end of the line". So, putting all this together, you can do:

```
grep '8[89]$' file
```

That will print any lines in the file `file` that end with an `8` followed by either another `8` or a `9`, in other words, lines ending with `88` or `89`.